# Difference between htons and ntohs function in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking, endianness

**I don't think that the marked questions and answers do meet my expectations** The link -->  [Same output for htonl() and ntohl() on an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423368/4990642)   --> says *Network byte order is big-endian, host byte order is little-endian.* My confusion still goes on. Also, what is host? Still not answer most of my questions. **I think those voted the question for closing have misunderstood my question** ***I've voted to reopen***. Please reread and reopen the question.

---

I've read that network-byte-order always is represented in Big Endian. However, I didn't found formal source for that. I did a snippet to see the difference between both functions but on the same machine I get same results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //first part
    printf("%d\n", ntohs(12345));
    printf("%d\n", ntohs(12345) == 12345);
    // second part
    printf("%d\n", htons(12345));
    printf("%d\n", htons(12345) == 12345);
    //third part
    printf("%d\n", htons(htons(12345)));
    printf("%d\n", ntohs(ntohs(12345)));
    //fourth part
    printf("%d\n", ntohs(htons(12345)));
    return 0;
}
```

- If network-byte-order always is represented in Big Endian, why cannot
  I read printed value as `12345` in second part? tl;dr My machine is
  little-endian.

After I tried same code also on PowerPC which works with Big Endian, both first part and second part give same result `12345`. It is not interesting because of the machine's representation.

- What about third part? Is it De Morgan(pun intended!)? It yields same
  result with fourth part. So, why do we need if both functions do same
  task?
- What does it mean "**host**" in this context? My machine?
- I though that I could use the functions to check whether a machine
  uses little-endian or big-endian. However, It doesn't sound sanely
  after the intricacies.

Little-Endian Computer Output: (Mac OSX)

```
14640
0
14640
0
12345
12345
12345
```

Big-Endian Computer Output: (PowerPC)

```
root@debian-powerpc:~# gcc -c endian.c 
root@debian-powerpc:~# gcc endian.c -o  out 
root@debian-powerpc:~# ./out 
12345
1
12345
1
12345
12345
12345
```

Comment: Thats multiple questions in one -> off-topic. Most are confused and unclear -> off-topic. Looks like you either didn't really rread the documentation or din't understand it, possibly due to lack of basics. Sometimes it's a good idea to step back and have a look at the whole picture.

Comment: On a sidenote: your code invokes undefined behaviour, you're using wrong conversion type specifiers. So it does not show anything.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Because of the default argument promotions and the implicit declaration rules, there is no UB in this code.  (In particular, passing a `short` quantity to printf's `%d` is perfectly fine.) It _ought_ to be including `<arpa/inet.h>` for declarations of `htons` and `ntohs`, though.

Comment: htons and ntohs do the same thing: they reverse bytes or they don't do anything, depending on the endianness of the host

Comment: @zwol: 7.21.6.1p9: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined"

Comment: @toohonestforthissite 6.5.2.2p7 "... The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments"  Therefore, if an expression with type `short` is supplied as one of the variable arguments to `printf`, `printf` receives an `int`, which agrees with `%d`.

Comment: @zwol: This is wrong, as `uint16_t` could be `unsigned`, which is not the type expected by `%d`. The section I referenced is about that specific function's behaviour, not parameter passing **in general**. A function may very well specify more strict rules to valid parameters/conversions.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite No, that is a misinterpretation.  The rules of 6.5.2.2 apply first to all function calls, and in particular, default argument promotion happens for all parameters passed as "trailing arguments" for a variable argument list.  Only then do the specific rules for a library function apply.  Regarding the possibility that `uint16_t` might be `unsigned int` and therefore the code would have UB due to signed/unsigned mismatch, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior -- technically yes, practically no.

Comment: @zwol: "practically no" is a very weak position if there is absolutely no need to resort to it. What's the problem using the `inttypes.h` macro with the corrrect conversion type specifier?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Re; "htons and ntohs do the same thing". See this [good comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423338/same-output-for-htonl-and-ntohl-on-an-integer#comment15068730_11423371)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre **I respect your experiences but I don't think that the marked questions and answers do meet my expectations** The link --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423368/4990642 --> says _Network byte order is big-endian, host byte order is little-endian._ My confusion still goes on. Also, what is host? Still not answer most of my questions. **I think you have misunderstood my question** _**I've voted to reopen**_. Please reread and reopen the question.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite This is a test program.  It does not need to be perfectly portable.  OP wanted help understanding `htons` and `ntohs` and instead they got a bunch of natter in the comments about how their program might misbehave on a hypothetical 16-bit microcontroller whose calling convention treats `unsigned int` and `signed int` differently.  Can you see how that's not the ideal outcome for anyone?

Comment: @snr You will have better luck if you ask a set of new questions, one question per post, being as specific as you can about what it is you still don't understand after having read the linked questions.

Comment: @zwol Really thanks for your interest. But, **I don't write my questions giddy-pacedly** I thought and read on it for hours. I've read the both links before asking the question. One of the answers on former link says _Network byte order is big-endian, host byte order is little-endian._ However, the person closed the topic says _htons and ntohs do the same thing: they reverse bytes or they don't do anything, depending on the endianness of the host_. What is my wrong here about asking the question?

Comment: @snr Re; "why do we need if both functions do same task?" --> review [good comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423338/same-output-for-htonl-and-ntohl-on-an-integer#comment15068730_11423371) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423338/same-output-for-htonl-and-ntohl-on-an-integer#comment15068788_11423371).

Comment: @chux why don't `printf("%d\n", htons(12345));` print `12345` if If network-byte-order always is represented in Big Endian?

Comment: @snr The biggest problem with this post is that you're trying to ask several questions at once.  We want you to ask exactly one question per post.

Comment: there are several gold badge owners who can single-handledly reopen the question if they feel it's not a duplicate (they already gave very good advice on the question). I'm not going to reopen, personally.

Comment: @snr [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658339/difference-between-htons-and-ntohs-function-in-c?noredirect=1#comment90282843_51658339) is unclear  as posted in the question, the BE machine _did_ print `12345` as expected.  Are you asking why it printed something else on the LE MAC?  Yet I see the comments getting out of hand.  [TTFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTFN).

Comment: @chux Yes, I'm mentioning LE MAC. I think it would also print `12345` instead of `14640`. Because `htons` converts to BE format always??

Comment: @snr The `htons` function converts to BE format always so long as its input is in the host byte order. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @snr `ntohs(12345)` did convert 12345 (stored in LE format on the MAC) into a 2-byte BE bit pattern and  extended it to 4-bytes.  The trouble was that code then  gave this BE bit pattern  to `printf()`, which expected to receive a `int` value in LE order.  So code rather than printing 12345 (0x3039), printed 14640 (0x3930).  A good idea is to 1) separate the idea of value from encoding and 2) investigate with `%x` and hexadecimal constants.