# pdp endian with htonl and ntohl functions

Tags: c, sockets, bit-manipulation, endianness

I have read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423338/same-output-for-htonl-and-ntohl-on-an-integer#comment15068730_11423371) that,

> On a hypothetical *"stupid-endian"* C implementation where the bytes
>   are neither big-endian (ordered `4321`) nor little-endian (ordered
>   `1234`), but ordered for example `3214`, you would still have
>   `htonl(ntohl(x))`, but `htonl` and `ntohl` would not do the same
>   thing, they'd be 8-bit rotations in opposite directions. I hope that
>   no such architecture exists, but it could implement the sockets API
>   thanks to the fact that `htonl` and `ntohl` are separate functions.

But I can't comprehend and figure out meaning of *but `htonl` and `ntohl` would not do the samething, they'd be 8-bit rotations in opposite directions.* What will be happen if they are rotated in opposite ways. How will the funcitons behave logically?

Can you depict and explain its logic?

P.S. It means in this case that implementations of `htonl` and `ntohl` functions are different and **`htonl(x) != ntohl(x)`**

Comment: I’d like to highlight that your real question has nothing to do with htonl nor ntohl. You don’t understand the meaning of “rotating an int by byte(s) in either direction”. Once you dig that, the specific question you had will answer itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had an architecture that stored the value `0x01020304` internally as `0x04010203`.  An implementation of `ntohl` would need to rotate the bytes right by 1.

For example:

```
uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t n)
{
    unsigned char x = n & 0xff;
    uint32_t result = n >> 8;
    result |= x << 24;
}
```

This would convert the value `0x01020304` to `0x04010203`.  Calling `ntohl` on the result `0x04010203` would not give back `0x01020304` but would instead give you `0x03040102`.

To reverse the process you need to rotate *left* by 1 byte.  An implementation of `htonl` might look like this:

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t n)
{
    unsigned char x = (n & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    uint32_t result = n << 8;
    result |= x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir but, don't you write wrong the function name? I mean you need change htonl to ntohl an vice versa. Because network byte order always big-endian?